# Python regex: Multiple regex per string mutially excluding each other, such as in cell profiler?

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to recreate the regex capturing as it works in cellprofiler with python?
So that I compile multiple regex together, whereas the first one will capture a part of the string, store this capture in a variable, the next one is starting after the previous one and looks for another pattern etc?
I want to create a user input to how the format the users data ID is, and this seems to be a much easier user input than how I would know how to solve it with regex normally.

So in cellprofiler the following expression used on the string
't10_F0010_GFP_D2.tif' would give:

```
string='t10_F0010_GFP_D2.tif'
pattern=t(?P<Timepoint>[0-9]+)_F(?P<Site>[0-9]{4})_(?P<Channel>.*)_(?P<Well>[A-Z][0-9]).tif

Output:
Timepoint=10
Site=0010
Channel=GFP
Well=D2
```

So the pattern would translate to:
start with one 't', capture one or more following numbers as 'timepoint', 
requires to be followed by '*F', capture four digits [0-9] after that as 'Site',
requires to be followed by '*', capture anything after that until next '_' as 'Channel', capture one letter followed by one number as 'Well', requires to and in .tif.

Can this be reproduced in python somehow?

Comment: That is a valid Python regex already... Just escape the final dot and use raw string: `r'(?P<Timepoint>[0-9]+)_F(?P<Site>[0-9]{4})_(?P<Channel>.*)_(?P<Well>[A-Z][0-9])\.tif'. After matching, use `.group('Timepoint')` etc to get the contents of the named groups (named groups are the parentheses with `?P<name_here>`)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know .group() would accept inputs like that. That's great news!

Comment: Related documentation - https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match()` with `groupdict()`

**Ex:**

```
import re

string='t10_F0010_GFP_D2.tif'
pattern=re.compile("t(?P<Timepoint>[0-9]+)_F(?P<Site>[0-9]{4})_(?P<Channel>.*)_(?P<Well>[A-Z][0-9]).tif")
for k, v in pattern.match(string).groupdict().items(): # --> {'Well': 'D2', 'Site': '0010', 'Channel': 'GFP', 'Timepoint': '10'}
    print("{}={}".format(k, v))
```

**Output:**

```
Well=D2
Site=0010
Channel=GFP
Timepoint=10
```